# Integrals involving fractions of exponentials

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration

I am trying to calculate the average degree of a complex network, which requires me to solve for the following integral:

$$\int \mathrm{d} x \frac{\exp{\left[-x -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right]}}{1 + a\exp{(-x)}},$$

where $\mu$, $\sigma$, and $a$ are known constants. Any advice on how to tackle this integral would be greatly appreciated.

So far, I have tried integration by parts, as well as substitutions of the type $s = \exp{(-x)}$ or identities in terms of the hyperbolic trig functions. Unfortunately, none of these got me far.

Comment: Try googling for Mordell integral

Comment: What is the domain of integration?

Comment: Thanks @მამუკაჯიბლაძე! The Mordell integral is definitely related.

@LiorSilberman: I need the indefinite integral, but $x$ is a real number.

Comment: For $a=0$, you have an error function. Expanding in powers of $a$, you have a whole series of error functions. There won't be a nice, simple form.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt What you say might provide an interesting expansion for Mordell integrals, I don't see whether it is something new or not. Could you work out in more detail what do you have in mind and what do you obtain explicitly?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე - thank you, sure, I'll put it together sometime later today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can obtain power series in $a$ by expanding in geometric series. Since the specific treatment depends on the integration region, let's introduce lower and upper limits, $y_0 <y$,
$$
I = \int_{y_0 }^{y} dx\, \frac{\exp \left[ -x -\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{x-\mu }{\sigma } \right)^{2} \right] }{1+a\exp (-x)}
$$
For $|a|<e^{y_0 } $, we have $|a\exp (-x)| < 1$ and we can expand in a geometric series as
\begin{eqnarray*}
I &=& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty } (-a)^n \int_{y_0 }^{y} dx\, \exp \left[ -(n+1) x -\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{x-\mu }{\sigma } \right)^{2} \right] \\
&=& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty } (-a)^n \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2} } \sigma \ e^{((n+1) \sigma^{2} -2\mu)(n+1)/2} \cdot \\
& & \hspace{2.5cm} \left[ \mbox{erf} \left( \frac{(n+1)\sigma^{2} -\mu +y}{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right) - \mbox{erf} \left( \frac{(n+1)\sigma^{2} -\mu +y_0 }{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right) \right]
\end{eqnarray*}
On the other hand, for $|a|>e^y $, we have $|\exp (x) /a| <1$, and we can alternatively write and expand
\begin{eqnarray*}
I &=& \frac{1}{a} \int_{y_0 }^{y} dx\, \frac{\exp \left[-\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{x-\mu }{\sigma } \right)^{2} \right] }{1+\exp (x)/a} \\
&=& \frac{1}{a} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty } \left(-\frac{1}{a} \right)^{n} \int_{y_0 }^{y} dx\, \exp \left[ nx -\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{x-\mu }{\sigma } \right)^{2} \right] \\
&=& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty } \left(-\frac{1}{a} \right)^{n+1} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2} } \sigma \ e^{(n \sigma^{2} +2\mu)n/2} \cdot \\
& & \hspace{2.5cm} \left[ \mbox{erf} \left( \frac{n\sigma^{2} +\mu -y}{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right) - \mbox{erf} \left( \frac{n\sigma^{2} +\mu -y_0 }{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right) \right]
\end{eqnarray*}
Finally, for $|a|\in \ ]e^{y_0 } ,e^y [$, we can separate into two integration intervals, $[y_0,\ln |a|\, [$ and $]\, \ln |a|,y]$, and use the applicable expansion from above in each case to obtain the combined result. In the case of negative $a$, one will have to specify how the boundary at $\ln |a|$ is approached from either side, corresponding to the pole in the original integrand; for example, one might specify a principal value prescription.

Comment: As mentioned in a comment, I hoped to extract something interesting for Mordell integrals, but now I am somehow confused. Does this tend to a definite limit when $y_0\to-\infty$ and $y\to+\infty$? Sorry, I never knew well how to correctly swap summations and limits...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე - sure, taking the upper and/or lower limits to infinity is not a problem, the series converge fine. The trickier part is assembling things at $\ln |a|$, where you're taking a limit towards the edge of the circle of convergence from both sides.

Answer (score 3):

[Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) "is a method for deciding whether a function has an elementary function as an indefinite integral, and if it does, for determining that indefinite integral."

[Mathematica knows this algorithm](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#23196).
However, it returns the integral unevaluated, even in the special case when $\mu=0,\sigma=1,a=1$, and even when using the Rubi package:

[image]

So, it is highly unlikely that this indefinite integral is an elementary function.

Answer (score 2):

Decided to mention in more detail what I said in a comment to the question.
The corresponding *definite* integral is expressible through the Mordell integral.

From the introduction of [Vector-valued higher depth quantum modular forms and higher Mordell integrals](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022247X19306651) by Bringmann, Kaszian and Milas (free version [in arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.06261)):

> The Mordell integral is usually defined as a function of two variables$$h(z)=h(z;\tau):=\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{\cosh(2\pi zw)}{\cosh(\pi w)}e^{\pi i\tau w^2}dw,\tag{1.1}$$where $z\in\mathbb C$ and $\tau\in\mathbb H$, the complex upper half-plane. Integrals of this form were studied by many mathematicians including Kronecker, Lerch, Ramanujan, Riemann, Siegel, and of course Mordell, who proved that a whole family of integrals reduces to $(1.1)$.

Two questions here on MO about Mordell integrals: [Asymptotic expansion of the Mordell integral](https://mathoverflow.net/q/162808/41291), [Conceptual meaning of a non-linear relation connecting $6$ Mordell integrals?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/350745/41291) It is also mentioned in my own (incomplete) [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/159219/41291) to one of my questions here.

Answer (score 1):

Note
$$
\int  \frac{\exp{\left[-x -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right]}}{1 + a\exp{(-x)}}dx
=
\int \frac{\exp{\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right]}}{ \exp(x)+ a}dx .
$$
Even this
$$
\int\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{e^x+1}dx
$$
is not known to Maple, although
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{e^x+1}dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}} .
$$

Comment: It should be straightforward to prove that $\exp(-x^2\!/2)/(\exp(x)+1)$ has no elementary antiderivative, by applying Liouville's theorem, as in the [answer to another MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/108616).